Draw arrow between two points in a list in TikZ
I am trying to connect a set of dots with arrows using tkiz. I am trying to demonstrate the motion of something as a function of time with the arrow indicating the motion. I can get the dots where I want by just having a list of the x coordinates and using \foreach to draw them. I have tried searching and am not seeing anything referencing what I want to do. My code for drawing the arrows is
\foreach \x in {0,1.2,2.4,3.6,4,4.4,4.8,6.8,8.8}
    \draw[->] (\x,0.5) -- (\x+1,0.5);

but this just draws an arrow of length 1 at the coordinate rather than going to the next coordinate.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Welcome to TeX.SE! please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

You can remember=\x as \xlast and use initially to set the first one or manually set it before the loop. Or you can use the loop within the path, but I think the first will be easier if every segment needs an arrow.

Essentially tikz pgf - Connect points in array with \foreach - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange

Welcome. // Please see one possible solution below. // Please make it a habit, to post only code, which compiles - yours doesn't : saves a lot of time and answers questions by itself, i.e. reduces comments, which are discussion in disguise. Thank you

Here are two different approaches for you.
Motion 1
Why don't you show just the dots? It already visualizes motion. To do so, just place nodes with empty text \node[dot] at (\x,.5) {}; inside the \foreach loop
Motion 2
Start with motion 1, and then draw just small lines with an arrow, leaving out the first point of your list. Note:

dot radius set to 4 pt via minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0
introducing a little shift to better see the arrows \draw[<-,colr,xshift=-2pt] (\x,-.5) -- +(-2pt,0);
balance both parameters, here 4pt and 2pt, also wrt your points location


\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[
    dot/.style={fill=black,circle,minimum size=4pt,inner sep=0},
    >={Stealth},
    colr/.style={red!50},
 ]
    % ~~~ help grid ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[teal!50] (0,-1) grid (9,2);
    
    % ~~~ motion 1 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[gray] (0,.5) -- (8.8,.5);
    \foreach \x in {0,1.2,2.4,3.6,4,4.4,4.8,6.8,8.8}    
        \node[dot] at (\x,.5) {};

    
    % ~~~ motion 2 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[colr] (0,-.5) -- (8.8,-.5);
    \foreach \x in {0,1.2,2.4,3.6,4,4.4,4.8,6.8,8.8}    
        \node[dot] at (\x,-.5) {};

    \foreach \x in {  1.2,2.4,3.6,4,4.4,4.8,6.8,8.8}
        \draw[<-,colr,xshift=-2pt] (\x,-.5) -- +(-2pt,0);
        
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

